# What's the best way to align binary operators to the right of a relation symbol?

Tags: align

I know that you're generally told to align binary operators to the right of a relation symbol like this (using `{align*}`):

```
\begin{align*}
x={}&a+b+c\\
    &+d+e+f
\end{align*}
```

But would it look better (though be more error prone) to do something like this to get the + exactly flush with the a?

```
\begin{align*}
x={}&a+b+c\\
    &{+}\: d+e+f
\end{align*}
```

(That is, use braces to turn the + into an ordinary symbol and add the medium space between the + and the d by hand.)

Edit: I'm trying to do exactly what's said in rule 3.3.5b, "Break at conjunctions and align to the right of the first verb", on page 46 of *Mathematics into Type* (updated edition, 1999).

Comment: I'd never want to align the `+` to the `a`. :)

Comment: I know a lot of folks would consider this a hack, but I'd use `\phantom` in the following way `\begin{align*}
x&=a+b+c\&\phantom{ {}=a}+d+e+f
\end{align*}` which looks [like this](http://i.imgur.com/3WWJI.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First I want to summarize and discuss the variants.

```
\begin{align*}
x={}&a+b+c\\
    &+d+e+f
\end{align*}
```

> [image: Unaligned]

TeX adds space around binary operators in display and text style, thus the `+` is moved to the right and destroys the alignment.

The variant of cmhughes aligns the `+` signs. Because the horizontal space matters only, the example uses `\hphantom`:

```
\begin{align*}
x={}&a+b+c\\
    &\hphantom{a}+d+e+f
\end{align*}
```

> [image: Alignment on plus signs]

The alignment on the first binary operator on the right side of the equation is a little arbitrary. Also `a` could be a huge summand moving the second line far to the right margin.

I agree with MSC that suppressing the white space before the plus sign makes sense.
He removes the property of a binary operator of the plus sign and manually adds the space for the following operand:

```
\begin{align*}
x={}&a+b+c\\  
    &{+}\: d+e+f
\end{align*}
```

> [image: Alignment on the right side]

It can also be implemented the other way round by removing the space in front of the
binary operator:

```
\begin{align*}
x={}&a+b+c\\
    &\mskip-\medmuskip+ d+e+f
\end{align*}
```

This can also be implemented as macro:

```
\newcommand*{\leftbin}{%
  \nonscript\mskip-\medmuskip
  \mathbin
}

\begin{align*}
x={}&a+b+c\\
    &\leftbin+d+e+f
\end{align*}
```

It can also be used as `\leftbin{+}`. The space is only added in text and display math styles. Therefore `\nonscript` is used (see comment of egreg).
`\mathbin` ensures that the next math atom or sub formula is treated as binary operator.

Comment: Wouldn't `\nonscript\mskip-\medmuskip` be better than `\mathchoice`?

Comment: Not a very frequently used primitive indeed. :)

Comment: @egreg The perfect one for this purpose. It seems that Knuth had similar problems. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I like

```
\begin{align*}
   x&=a+b+c\\
    &\quad+d+e+f
\end{align*}
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting topic. I always do:

```
\begin{align*}
x=&\ a+b+c\\
  &+ d+e+f
\end{align*}
```

but I'm not sure if that has any downsides.